# Name Order By Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have List of People Names listed in my Site. Now 2 people are the senior most person so i want their names to be at the beginning.

i.e

**Input**

**Names**

GIjoe

Spiderman

Superman

Batman

SpaceGhost

Caveman

Swatcats

Heman

**Output**

Heman

Superman

Spiderman

GIjoe

Batman

SpaceGhost

Caveman

Swatcats

Now I want Heman and Superman at the beginning.What is the Mysql Query that Suits that.

Comment: And what's the order for other people? PS: it is a good idea to check correct answers sometimes

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `name` IN ('Heman', 'Superman')
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
         END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
ORDER BY  `fname` IN ('Heman','superman') DESC;
```